# Ruby on rails: how to update an div with partial without making an ajax call to server

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, partials

I want to update an div with contents of a partial when a user clicks on a radio button. Now the contents of that partial are static html (a form may be). So because I do not have any data to fetch from the server I am reluctant to make an ajax call to server just to fetch that partial and update the div. Here is what I have tried.

```
 function loadControlPanel(type)
      {
        alert(type);
        $(controlPanelDiv).appendChild("<%=  render :partial => 'layouts/agency_selection' %>");
      }


<input type="radio" name="view" value="agencies" onClick ="loadControlPanel(this.value)" /> Agencies
```

But this doesn't work because the render  replaces the entire partial there along with the new lines which throws javascript errors in the `function loadControlPanel(type)`.

Is there any way to overcome this? or some other simpler solution?

Thanks
Shaunak

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why dont you render the static part in your layout in a hidden div, then clone that id and put it in your innerHTML using javascrtipt?

By the way just calling "render :partial" does not mean its an Ajax call.

Comment: I am aware that render is not an ajax call. In fact ajax call is the exact thing that I was trying to avoid. Even though I found a work around to the above problem (as i have mentioned in my answer below) i liked your solution.  Its more a more natural solution. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

OKay here is the work around i have found to get around this. I am calling 'gsub' on the render to replace the newlines with nothing. I am still open to more elegant solutions though.

```
function loadControlPanel(type)
      {
        alert(type);
        $(controlPanelDiv).innerHTML = '<%=  (render :partial => "layouts/agency_selection").gsub("\n","") %>';
      }
```